# Is it possible to have AuthorizationRule on CSLA CriteriaBase

Tags: c#, csla

Is it possible to have AuthorizationActions.WriteProperty rules on a CriteriaBase in CSLA ?

I have a screen with a bunch of filters and I want to enable only those that the user has access (ex: some user can't search in other regions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `CriteriaBase` doesn't support any rules.  There's no requirement to subclass it though for criteria type classes; you can use `BusinessBase<T>` as your criteria subclass, which will support authorization and validation rules.

I believe the current recommendation is to move way from using `CriteriaBase` at all, especially since newer versions can pass multiple simple types or types which implement `IMobileObject` directly, so you'd really only need a class to represent your criteria if there needs to support business rules, such as your authorization rule, or perhaps a validation rule that requires a minimum number of criteria properties to be set.